# Extend linux root drive in Dual Boot OS

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-mint, swap

[image: Gparted sreenshot]

Any idea how to add the 31GB unallocated space to /dev/sda7? I disabled linux swap(swapoff) but still can't add the space or move it in the extended partition.

I am running gparted from live usb. The Windows partition is located on /dev/sda6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the NTFS partition `/dev/sda3` down next to `/dev/sda2` to leave the unallocated gap next to the extended partition `/dev/sda4`.

Now extend `/dev/sda4` downwards to encompass the free space, which will now be below the ext4 partition `/dev/sda7`, which can now be extended downwards to include the free space.

You will need to do most of these operations from an external Live Boot disc, as you cannot modify active partitions.

You would be advised to run `boot-repair` after `gparted` has finished (you may need to install this if your live disc doesn't include it by default).

Above all, make a copy of the whole drive before you do anything else, so that you can recover your present configuration should anything go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't, you can only 'extend' a partition with space that follows it, its how the parition tables address space.

In your case you can extend sda7 using sda5 and then sda6.

Now if you have LVM (Logical Volume Manager) configuered for your Linux installation then you can format that unallocated space as a new partition and add it to the volume group.

Can you share /etc/fstab ?